# Java String Exception

Tags: java, string, exception

The following code is used for convert string to long value.
When i call the function by `StringToInt64("119.64");`
It shows the error as:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
>           at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1955)
>           at Test.StringToInt64(Test.java:13)
>           at Test.main(Test.java:25)

The code:

```
long StringToInt64(String s)
{
    long ret_val = 0, k = 1;

    for (int j = s.length(); j > 0; j--)
    {
        if(s.substring(j - 1,1) != ".") // Error Line
        {
            String t = s.substring(j-1,1);

            ret_val = (ret_val + (Integer.parseInt(t)*k));
            k = k * 10;
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}
```

The expected answer is 11964.

Please help me to solve this...

Comment: Instead of `substring()`, you should use `charAt(int index)` which returns a char which can be compared using `!=` (strings need to be compared using `equals()`). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Comment: Or even simpler: `Long.parseLong(s.replaceFirst("\\.", ""))`

Answer (score 1):

Your beginIndex is bigger than the endindex and that causes the excpetion.

You call in first iteration `s.substring(5,1)` where 5 ist the `beginIndex` and 1 is the `endIndex`.

If you what to have a string with length one you have to change your code to:

```
static long StringToInt64(String s)
{
    long ret_val = 0, k = 1;

    for (int j = s.length()-1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        if(!s.substring(j - 1,j).equals(".")) // Error Line
        {
            String t = s.substring(j-1,j);

            ret_val = (ret_val + (Integer.parseInt(t)*k));
            k = k * 10;
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}
```

You can see that substring must called with parameter j-1 and j.

Also you have to compare strings with the equals method nit with `!=`.

Instead of `substring` you can also use `chatAt()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code have many problems:

1.`substring(begin, end)`, not `substring (begin, size)`

2.When compare String, use `equals()`, not `==`

3.Why you call `s.substring(j-1,j)` 2 times?

4.If you want to get 1 character from String, use `charAt()`

5.Why you call `Integer.parseInt`? If you can call this function, why not using `Long.parseLong()` instead of writing this `StringToInt64()` function.

6.With Java convention, it should be `stringToInt64()`, not `StringToInt64()` and `retVal`, not `ret_val`

7.should use `a += b` instead of `a = a + b`

```
static long stringToInt64(String s) {
    long retVal = 0, k = 1;
    for (int j = s.length(); j > 0; j--) {
        char t = s.charAt(j - 1);
        if (t < '0' || t > '9') //ignore character not in '0' - '9'
            continue;
        retVal += ((t - '0') * k);
        k *= 10;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement it:

```
long stringToInt64(String s) {
    long result = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c != '.') {
            result = result * 10 + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here an even nicer variant (which behaves slightly different for characters which are not digits)

```
long stringToInt64(String s) {
    long result = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            result = result * 10 + (c - '0');
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

What I changed:

- avoid using strings of length 1 by using `char`
- use foreach instead of for
- change the direction of the loop (because of foreach)
- no need anymore for using the variable `k`
- Second variant: Avoid using parseInt for single-character strings. This needs a stricter validation of the input (in this we skip everything which isn't '0'..'9')
- Rename the function according to [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Personal preference: instead of `ret_val`/`retVal` I used the variable name `result`.